# Regular expression rule: match a constant and the last part of the string

Tags: regex

I am not really good at writing regular expressions but i need to match some parts of a URL.

`http://example.com/service-page/service1/sub-service2/other-service/`

my attempt looks like

`service-page/(.?.+?)$`

and the capture looks like `service1/sub-service2/other-service/`

but i need only to match if there is constant `service-page` inside the url and to capture the last part of the url `other-service`

`http://example.com/[service-page]/service1/sub-service2/[other-service]/`

Comment: Are you using some kind of framework? Many come with built in types to process URLs.

Comment: i am trying to write a custom rule for wordpress WP_Rewrite class, that will parse my request and math the existence of my base "service-page" and the last part of the url which is the page i am interested in "other-service"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to confess that I don't have WP to test with, but based on working with other regex engines, I don't see why this shouldn't work:

```
service-page/.*?([^/]+)/?$
```

Answer (score 1):

To capture the name of the last subfolder:

```
ServicePageSubFolder("http://example.com/service-page/service1/sub-service2/other-service/");

public string ServicePageSubFolder(string url)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"service-page.*/([^/]+)/?");
    Match match = regex.Match(url);
    if (match.Success)
        return match.Groups[1].Value;
    return null;
}
```

Good luck with your quest.

Comment: maybe this works in c#? because on my regex tool it shows me that capture string is "service-page/service1/sub-service2/other" but i need the match.Groups[1].Value to be "other-service"

Comment: @Constantine, Sorry, just missed the fact the \w only covers all letters, digits and underscore. I replaced \w with [^/] meaning that any char except / is expected.